# Group a HTML output with XSLT(muenchian grouping?)

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

I would like the output to be grouped in a special way, maybe using muenchian grouping? but I'm stuck

Here is the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<NTC_PUBLICATION xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NM_TORP_NTC>
            <PUBLISH_NUMBER>138</PUBLISH_NUMBER>
            <TERM>Temporary</TERM>
            <NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
                <CHART_NUM>NZ 21 (INT 641), NZ 522, NZ 5219</CHART_NUM>
            </NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
        </NM_TORP_NTC>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NM_TORP_NTC>
            <PUBLISH_NUMBER>139</PUBLISH_NUMBER>
            <TERM>Temporary</TERM>
            <NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
                <CHART_NUM>NZ 522, NZ 5321</CHART_NUM>
            </NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
        </NM_TORP_NTC>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NM_TORP_NTC>
            <PUBLISH_NUMBER>141</PUBLISH_NUMBER>
            <TERM>Preliminary</TERM>
            <NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
                <CHART_NUM>NZ 268</CHART_NUM>
            </NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
        </NM_TORP_NTC>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
    <SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
        <NM_TORP_NTC>
            <PUBLISH_NUMBER>143</PUBLISH_NUMBER>
            <TERM>Preliminary</TERM>
            <NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
                <CHART_NUM>NZ 26, NZ 268</CHART_NUM>
            </NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST>
        </NM_TORP_NTC>
    </SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
</NTC_PUBLICATION>
```

And here is the XSLT stylesheet I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl exslt">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
    <xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="@chart"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div>
            <xsl:variable name="result">
                <xsl:for-each select="//NM_TORP_NTC">
                    <xsl:call-template name="split">
                        <xsl:with-param name="notice" select="PUBLISH_NUMBER"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="NM_CHART_AFFECTED_LIST/CHART_NUM"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="term" select="TERM"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$result"/>
            <table style="padding-left:200px;align:center;">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="function-available('msxsl:node-set')">
                        <xsl:call-template name="sub-class">
                            <xsl:with-param name="result" select="msxsl:node-set($result)"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="sub-class">
                            <xsl:with-param name="result" select="exslt:node-set($result)"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </table>
            <!-- Apply the templates for each Notice -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM/NM_TORP_NTC"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split">
        <xsl:param name="notice"/>
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:param name="term"/>
        <xsl:if test="substring-after($string,',')!=''">
            <item>
                <xsl:attribute name="notice">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$notice"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="chart">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,',')"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="term">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$term"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </item>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-after($string,',')!=''">
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="notice" select="$notice"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,',')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="term" select="$term"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($string,','))">
                <item>
                    <xsl:attribute name="notice">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$notice"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="chart">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="term">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$term"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </item>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sub-class">
        <xsl:param name="result"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$result/item[count(. | key('item', @chart)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@chart" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@chart"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('item', @chart)">
                        <xsl:sort select="@notice" data-type="number"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$pos!=1">
                            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@notice"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:if test="@term='Temporary'">
                            <xsl:text>(T)</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@term='Preliminary'">
                            <xsl:text>(P)</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently the output is like so ((T) is for Temporary and (P) for Preliminary):

```
NZ 268     143 (P)
NZ 5219    138 (T)
NZ 522     138 (T)
NZ 5321    139 (T)
NZ 21      138 (T)
NZ 26      143 (P)
NZ 268     141 (P)
NZ 522     139 (T)
```

I would like the output to be grouped like so, in a table:

```
NZ 21      138 (T)
NZ 26      143 (P)
NZ 268     141 (P), 143 (P)
NZ 522     139 (T), 141 (P)
NZ 5219    138 (T)
NZ 5321    139 (T)
```

Comment: Please reduce the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: This is already reduced from a much bigger file. I think everything here is necessary.

Comment: I don't think the tokenizing part is necessary for grouping the results thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your XSLT copies out the `$result` variable (for debugging), and if you look closely there is a difference between items you wish to group

```
<item notice="141" chart="NZ 268" term="Preliminary"></item>
....
<item notice="143" chart=" NZ 268" term="Preliminary"></item>
```

There is a space before one of the values of the `chart` attribute, and this means the values are different as far as grouping is concerned.

The solution is simply to use `normalize-space` to trim the spaces when creating the `chart` attribute.

Try changing your `split` template to this....

```
<xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="notice"/>
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="term"/>
    <xsl:if test="substring-after($string,',')!=''">
        <item>
            <xsl:attribute name="notice">
                <xsl:value-of select="$notice"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="chart">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($string,','))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="term">
                <xsl:value-of select="$term"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </item>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($string,',')!=''">
            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="notice" select="$notice"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,',')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="term" select="$term"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($string,','))">
            <item>
                <xsl:attribute name="notice">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$notice"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="chart">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($string)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="term">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$term"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Or maybe simplify it a bit to this....

```
<xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="notice"/>
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="term"/>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($string)!=''">
        <item>
            <xsl:attribute name="notice">
                <xsl:value-of select="$notice"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="chart">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($string, ','),','))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="term">
                <xsl:value-of select="$term"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </item>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($string,',')">
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="notice" select="$notice"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,',')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="term" select="$term"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine ! Thank you very much :)